# problem with else if statement not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom WordPress filter. I am importing api data to a form. My first IF statement works (when district not empty). But I can't get the else if working to populate the 2nd field. The 2nd result in the JSON has no value for district. What I am trying to do is separate the results to display House rep in one field and Senators in another. (There are actually two Senate results but I don't now how to separate the results). Each result needs to be in different form fields.

```
add_filter('frm_pre_create_entry', 'import_fields');
function import_fields($values){
  if ( $values['form_id'] == 12 ) {
    $zipcode = $values['item_meta'][71];
    $api_request = 'http://whoismyrepresentative.com/getall_mems.php?zip='.$zipcode.'&output=json';
    $api_response = wp_remote_get( $api_request );
    $api_data = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $api_response ), true );
    foreach ( $api_data["results"] as $member ) {
      if ( $member["district"] != '' ) {
        $values['item_meta'][72] = $member['name'];
        $values['item_meta'][73] = $member['phone'];
        $values['item_meta'][74] = $member['office'];
      } else if ( $member["district"] == '' ) {
        $values['item_meta'][75] = $member['name'];
        $values['item_meta'][76] = $member['phone'];
        $values['item_meta'][77] = $member['office'];
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return $values;
}
```

I am new here, please go easy on me.

Comment: You `break` at the end of the first loop, which stops execution and breaks out of the loop, is that your problem?

Comment: The break was the problem!

Comment: For the else if statement, I need to display 2 results, in different set of fields. How would I break this up? There will always be a maximum of 3 results, 1 house and two Senate.

Answer (score 0):

just like @billyonecan said, that break looks weird.

PS: You don't even need to specify the 'else if' condition... simply replace the 'else if' by 'else'

```
...
    } else if ( $member["district"] == '' ) {
...
```

becomes

```
...
    } else {
...
```

In your case it won't make any difference, it's just good practices

Comment: `else if` will check for a specific criteria where as `else` will perform a function for *anything* other than the specified ones above in the initial `if()`'s

Comment: You are right, I don't need the else if. I was trying to get the results to filter. How would I go about adding a 3rd value? There are 3 results with each call, 1 House and 2 Senate.